# MySQL - insert row after sort

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

if i have this table:

perma_table:

```
+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |
+-------+-------+
|   a   |   5   |
|   c   |   7   |
|   a   |   8   |
|   b   |   9   |
|   a   |   7   |
|   c   |   6   |
|   a   |   8   |
+-------+-------+
```

i want to make

inserted_table:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|   a   |   5   |   1   |
|   a   |   7   |   2   |
|   a   |   8   |   3   |
|   a   |   8   |   4   |
|   b   |   9   |   5   |
|   c   |   6   |   6   |
|   c   |   7   |   7   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

how to do this?
im using code igniter (php), is this all of this method can be done by using query, without using CI active record/php function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single query

```
CREATE TABLE inserted_table as
SELECT A,B,@num:=@num+1 AS C
FROM perma_table,(select @num:=0) temp
ORDER BY A,B;
```

Comment: you're first, thank you! if the field i sort is alphabetic, can i just put `ORDER BY A,B` without mention C and etc?

Comment: glad that I could help. Yes you can just put ORDER BY A,B. But keep in mind that sorting number and string is different.

Comment: oh, like A,AA,B,BB instead of (like number) A,B,AA,BB am i right?

Comment: how to do this with insertion? i cant do `SELECT A,B,@num:=@num+1 AS C
FROM perma_table,(select @num:=0) temp`, it randomized it even too wide,

Answer (score 1):

If you want just a query to do it, its so simple:
Insert it normally, after inserted you can select
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY A, B, C ASC

But if you want to keep this order, without at any select without order you can create a view or a new table like

```
CREATE VIEW inserted_table AS
SELECT A, B, @id = @id+1 AS C FROM perma_table
ORDER BY A,B;
```

OR a new table (no view)

```
CREATE TABLE inserted_table AS
SELECT A, B, @id = @id+1 AS C FROM perma_table
ORDER BY A,B;
```

With view you can insert any value on perma_table, the inserted_table will automaticaly generated, if you choose the second case, you heave to recreate the table averytime when you edit perma_table

Comment: thank you! and, if i just want to insert it (inserted_table was created) every i execute  the query, i can `INSERT INTO inserted_table AS
SELECT A, B, @id = @id+1 AS C FROM perma_table
ORDER BY A,B;`. am i doing it right?